# sessionFactory null ao tentar realizar select no banco

Tags: java, jsf, mvc, spring

Bom dia,
estou utilizando Spring e JSF. Queria fazer uma consulta ao banco e retornar os dados de uma tabela, porém no método que faço a busca, ao chamar o sessionFactory, ele esta vindo null. Realmente não consegui encontrar o problema.

```
/*classe DAO*/

package br.com.racionalgames.pta.dao;
import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import br.com.racionalgames.pta.model.UploadFiles;

@Repository("ListPlanilhasDao")
@Transactional
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ListPlanilhasDaoImpl implements ListPlanilhasDao {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<UploadFiles> getListPlanilha() throws Exception {

        List<UploadFiles> lista = null;
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM pta.criterios_multiskill";

        try {
            lista = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(sql).list();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Erro no DAO: " + e);
        }

        return (List<UploadFiles>) lista;
    }

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }
}

    *spring-config.xml  <bean id="ListPlanilhasDao" class="br.com.racionalgames.pta.dao.ListPlanilhasDaoImpl" />
*/
```

Comment: Você está criando o bean do DAO manualmente, correto? Como está construindo a _session factory_? Por que não passa ela como parâmetro para o bean do DAO que está criando? Pelo que tu passou não está tendo o _scan_ para construção do contexto, difícil saber como sua aplicação está.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

obrigado pela resposta, achei o problema. Eu estava esquecendo da injeção @ManagedProperty("#{listPlanilhasDao}"). Com isso iria vir null sempre.

Comment: Marque sua própria resposta como a correta :)